# .net web service consumed by php. Can enum and datetime types be understood by php?

Tags: php, .net, asmx

I have a web service hosted in asp.net which exposes a method that takes an object as parameter. This object has properties like DateTime? , enum, int , string.

Can php deal with DateTime or enum?

Comment: In what format are those returned from the service? XML? Then there's *some* type they will map to, even if it's just a string in PHP.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Please consider adding some code examples and more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP wouldn't be understanding .NET enum or or datetime types.  The proxy that is generated from the WSDL is what "understands" the interface that the ASMX publishes.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can.. but you should provide it well formatted before using it.
e.g. for datetime you should pass an example like the following: 2012-11-20T14:00:00
for enums you should supply the corresponding enum string..

I hope it helps